# inheritance mechanism in C++ a weird form of initializer list?

Tags: c++

While typing down a code snippet for the umpteenth time, I had a flash of insight which I am not sure is exactly true and hence my question on here

**The Code**

```
template <class T> class ListNode:public Node {

public:
  T_val;
  ListNode (T val);

}
```

**Question**

Is the `class ListNode : public Node` a sort of initializer list that initializes the public part of the object to the public part of the parent object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not. Initialization of Objects happens in constructors, not during the class definition. This is just plain inheritance, a concept that applies to classes only, not to objects. Classes do exist only at compiletime, not at runtime, so there can be no initialization. That the syntax for defining inheritance uses the colon `:` as well as the syntax for defining initialization lists in constructors does, does not mean there is a corellation. It's just a use of the same character in two cases that are distinct enough to avoid confusion, at least normally ;-)

This kind of multiple use happens a lot in C++. E.g. consider pairs of parentesis `()` wich are used both in function *declaration/definition* and function *call*. Or pairs of curly braces `{}` wich are used to define scope blocks (namespaces, classes, functions, scopes below function level) and to initialize objects (uniform initialization in C++11, aggregate initialization in C++98/03). Other examples are `&` ("address-of" and "binary and" operators vs. reference declaration), `delete` (`delete` operator and `operator delete` vs. deleted functions) and `<` etc (templates vs. coparison operators)